# Xdocument,Descendants in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the below code to get alexa page rank.

```
private int GetAlexaRank(string domain)
{
    var alexaRank = 0;
    try
    {
        var url = string.Format("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url={0}", domain);

        var doc = XDocument.Load(url);

        var rank = doc.Descendants("POPULARITY").Select(node => node.Attribute("TEXT").Value).FirstOrDefault();

        if (!int.TryParse(rank, out alexaRank))
            alexaRank = -1;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return alexaRank;
}
```

But I truly don't understand how does that code work???
Would you tell me exactly, what is the `"POPULARITY"` and `"TEXT"`? and where are they stored?
I don't understand this syntax: `doc.Descendants("POPULARITY").Select(node => node.Attribute("TEXT").Value).FirstOrDefault();`
Please!!!!

Comment: You need to take a look [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) first

Comment: @CuongLe dạ em mới vừa tự làm quen với XML, còn đôi chổ thắc mắc. Anh ơi, theo như dòng code trên thì POPULARITY là 1 node hả anh? Dữ liệu từ trang alexa được lưu vào đối tượng Xdocument, em có cách nào xem được file XML để biết POPULARITY chính xác được cung cấp và gọi như thế nào không ạ?

Comment: Please don't local language in here, yes you are right, you can use Chrome development tool to see or Fiddle to track xml from alexa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you navigating to the `url` you have in your code and take a look at the `XML` file structure.  You should see tags with `POPULARITY` and `TEXT`, by the look of your code these are the nodes/attributes/values that you are selecting.

[`.Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337483.aspx) returns a collection, and since you provide `POPULARITY` it will bring back the elements within the `<POPULARITY>` tag in your XML file.

You are then looking at each node in the `Collection` whose Descendants are `Popularity` and selecting an item with attribute `TEXT`. Your return the first value found, or null if the collection does not contain a node with attribute `TEXT`.

Comment: @vyclarks - from the code you provided, `TEXT` is an attribute.  `POPULARITY` should be a node that contains other elements inside it, .Descendants will return these elements.

Comment: Dear! How can I take a look at the XML file structure with `("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url={0}", domain);`???

Comment: @vyclarks - put a breakpoint on `var doc = XDocument.Load(url);` and inspect what `url` is.  From there you can get to the file.

Comment: hi dear! How about `if (!int.TryParse(rank, out alexaRank))
                    alexaRank = -1;`, I don't really understand this phrase: `!int.TryParse(rank, out alexaRank)`